# JSOUP generate css path and whitespace

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I am trying to get css path of element from JSOUP document.
This elemnt looks like this:

```
<div class="column" id="
                        datagrid147">
          <div>
            //Other data
          </div>
</div>
```

Problem is whitespace in ID, when I get css selector from JSOUP element, it contains whitespace therefore is incorrect and when I remove whitespace, selector will not work for that element. So how to get correct css selector for element defined like this in JSOUP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper solution would most likely involve cleaning attributes first (maybe with `trim()` method), then selecting elements.

But way around could be using `[attr~=regex]` selector, which in your case could look like `div[id~=^\\s+datagrid147$]`.

Another way could be using `[attr$=value]` where attribute `attr` ends with specified `value` like `div[id$=datagrid147]`

More help about selectors at: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Thank you.  I used regex solution and it is working like it should.